# Bike pedaling makes cracking noise under middle or high load

Tags: mountain-bike, crankset, bottom-bracket, noise

Can this be related to bottom bracket bearings of Race Face BB92, PressFit? The chain is freshly lubricated and quite a new one. No noice is produced when pedalling with low load or not pedalling.

I already had similar cracking noice from the same bottom bracket Race Face BB92 10 months ago when the crank was rotated even without chain: [Clicking / cracking noise rotating crank MTB](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/87984/clicking-cracking-noise-rotating-crank-mtb) It was resolved by changing the bottom bracket bearings in the end of March 2023. If this is the case, bearings are no much durable if they last just 10 months and 4500 km / 2800 miles.

Comment: If the symptoms are the same as when it was the BB isn't it then likely it is the BB again? 4500km is within the range of my expectations for a cartridge BB, are these supposed to last longer? You should check if there is any play in the BB, because then you know that needs attention. Unfortunately, lots of other things can cause creaking when pedaling hard and sounds may appear before play becomes obvious.

Comment: That sounds like a poorly aligned chain to me.

Comment: Does it still creak pedalling under load standing up? If its less creaky standing up, perhaps you can clean and lube the seat tube or check the bolts around the saddle area. If creaks the same standing up, and the BB is "newish" I'd check if the cassette is totally dry on its freehub (it shouldnt be dry - lube it up if it is) or even freehub/hub bearings (might be worn or totally shot).

Comment: @WornChain Thanks for the ideas. On my previous bike, the cheap Shimano BB still works to this day, but on the other hand, it's much heavier than this. 4500 km and 1 year seems to me a weak endurance. Maybe it's the price for the tiny bearing balls and low BB weight.

Comment: @deeviate It makes sounds even while standing.
If I'm riding on a flat surface, the sounds are heard only while the force is being applied to the pedal, when the left and right foot are pushing alternately.
In the video I went uphill with a light gear and then it clicks almost all the time (I use SPD and push continuously with both legs in this case).
Thanks for the ideas guys. In the end, I will probably take the bike to the service. If there is a problem with the RaceFace BB again, I will replace the whole BB with another heavier and old school one, but more robust one.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by removing the pedals, clean and lubricate the threads and refit, test ride. If the noise persists, remove each crank arm and do the same. If still no better, remove the bottom bracket and check the fitting of the bottom bracket. I would not have a press fit bottom bracket frame for this reason. Hope this helps.